# Convert a single column into 2d Matrix in python

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe

I have data as shown below in a single column and i want to split that single column into n number of columns and name rows and columns. How can i do that in python ?

-----------sample data----------

```
5
3
5
0
0
1
0
0
18
23
11
1
2
10
1
0
5
6
1
0
1
1
1
0
158
132
150
17
```

------------ The output should look like ---------

```
     column0 column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
row1    5      0      18      2       5       1       158
row2    3      1      23      10      6       1       132
row3    5      0      11      1       1       1       150
row4    0      0      1       0       0       0       17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to use numpy and the reshape function

```
import numpy as np

k = np.array(data)
k.reshape([row,column],order='F')
```

As for your example. You mentioned the data is from a text file so to acquire the data from the text file and reshape

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt("sample-data.txt");
data.reshape([4,7],order='F')
```

output will be

```
Out[27]: 
array([[  5,   0,  18,   2,   5,   1, 158],
       [  3,   1,  23,  10,   6,   1, 132],
       [  5,   0,  11,   1,   1,   1, 150],
       [  0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,  17]])
```

I do not know the structure of the data but assuming it is in 1 giant column as seen in the sample above. When importing the data using `open`. The following happens.

```
data = open("sample-data.txt",'r').readlines()

data
Out[64]: 
['5\n',
 '3\n',
 '5\n',
 '0\n',
 '0\n',
 '1\n',
 '0\n',
 '0\n',
 '18\n',
 '23\n',
 '11\n',
 '1\n',
 '2\n',
 '10\n',
 '1\n',
 '0\n',
 '5\n',
 '6\n',
 '1\n',
 '0\n',
 '1\n',
 '1\n',
 '1\n',
 '0\n',
 '158\n',
 '132\n',
 '150\n',
 '17']
```

This results in an array of string values as the `\n` means next line. Assuming this is numerical data, you will want to use the code above to get the numbers.

Comment: It is returning back a value error "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (3,2)" and i also want to name columns and rows like c1,c2...cn and r1,r2..rn

Comment: The error as states, you have an array of 1 and it cannot reshape into a 3x2 array. How are you inputting your data into python?

Comment: I am opening the same data from a text file 'sample-data.txt':                           `import numpy as np

data = open("sample-data.txt", 'r').readlines()

k = np.array(data)
k.reshape([4,6],order='F')

print(k)`

Comment: you have 28 entries in the sample dataset so you cannot make a 4x6 matrix. importing is a different matter, Is your data like as in the example? If so than reading the lines like you are will make them strings which can cause a problem. I will update my post again.